# Get scoped relation in scope body or in class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

can you help to newbie, please?

I need something like:

```
scope :randomized, lambda { actual.offset( rand( actual.count ) ) }

def self.random
  randomized.first
end
```

problem is in count... it is called agains a model itself and not a scoped result...
So i got bigger number if i call

```
Model.other_scope.maybe_another.randomized
```

is it posible to get the scoped result in scope body? so i could call scoped_result.actual.count or is there some other solution, maybe more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this...

```
def self.random
  Model.order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

Comment: Isn't it inefficient? It select all records from database and then select one from an array doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that fits to my problem, thanks... but it breaks rails multidatabase principes, so if you know how to get the scoped result in scope body I would still curious. But thanks for this :)